# how to draw a line in visual c++ but have it render over time instead of immediately?

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to programming overall, and I know how to draw normal lines, and I've even seen a few videos and the source code on something like making those dvd logo screens, but I was wondering how you would have a line be formed across the distance between 2 points instead of having it appear immediately.

Comment: You need to use a library or OS API. Standard `c++` has no drawing at all.

Comment: Do you mean c++/clr, if so you should use that tag.

Comment: Draw a shorter line segment and sleep.